# lineat fitting instead of gaussian in models.Gaussian1D

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have a spectrum which I want to fit a gaussian distribution on it. In more detail, this is an absorption line in my spectra I want to fit on it.

```py
data_folder_path = '/home/marzie/Documents/new measurement section/measurement/test' #data address
molecules_wave_list = '/home/marzie/Documents/new measurement section/measurement/Table of DIBS (copy).txt' #source molecules (Hobbs data)

data_files = [file for file in os.listdir(data_folder_path) if file.endswith('.txt')]

for file in data_files: 
    #Reading data
    file_path = os.path.join(data_folder_path, file)
    wave, flux = np.loadtxt(file_path,unpack=True)
    file_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]    # Extract file name without extension
    #print(file_name)

    #Cut the spectrum for desired molecule
    with open(molecules_wave_list, 'r') as molec:  # Load list 
        next(molec) # to skip the first row
        for line in molec:        # Iterate over each line in the molec      
            molec_value = line.split() # Split the line into columns
            central_wave = float(molec_value[0]) # Extract the values from each column
            lineWidth = float(molec_value[1]) #lineWidth is the sigma defined in the Hobbs file...this is actually the width of the molecular line
            line_width = 2.3548*lineWidth
            idx = (wave >= central_wave - 5.0) & (wave <= central_wave + 5.0)
            waveNE = wave[idx]
            fluxNE = flux[idx]
            amplitude = np.max(fluxNE)
            g_init = models.Gaussian1D(amplitude, central_wave, line_width)
            fit_g = fitting.LevMarLSQFitter()
            g = fit_g(g_init, waveNE, fluxNE)            
            # Plot the data and fitted model
            plt.plot(waveNE, fluxNE)
            plt.plot(waveNE, g(waveNE))
            plt.title('Gaussian Fit')
            plt.xlabel('Wavelength')
            plt.ylabel('Flux')
            plt.show()
```

I wrote the above code using the models.Gaussian1D but the fitted distribution is linear instead of gaussian.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! The fitting procedure itself [looks fine](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/modeling/fitting.html#simple-1-d-model-fitting), so the error must be in the data itself. I would advise to edit the question and add exemplary data for waveNE, fluxNE, amplitude, central_wave and line_width to be able to reproduce what is going on. See also how to produce a [mre] to showcase a specific behaviour.

Comment: Might be an "initial value" problem on a non-linear fit. Are you sure about the mu and sigma guesses?

Comment: ...and a path with white spaces hurts my eyes ;)